# I want my Ghostscript to output PNG pagenames starting with a higher number, e.g. "31". How?

Tags: png, ghostscript

Using Ghostscript I want to create ~330 PNG files from a PDF (photobook I was given as a gift). Now I want to put these pictures online. I'm aware of the method to use `-sOutputFile=somename--%03d.png` which will give me numbered PNG filenames along the pattern `somename--001.png`, `somename--002.png`, etc. However, I want to put  ~25-30 more pictures online, and these should have the lower numbered names.

**Question:** I need to have filenames for the converted PDF output start with "31", i.e. `somename--031.png`. If I use the Ghostscript numbering method, I do have to manually rename all the PNG files...  **shudder**. **Is there a way to let Ghostscript's numbering start with "031"?** Some hidden parameter to `%03d` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any hidden parameter for the `%03d` notation to make it start its numbering scheme with an offset.

However, here is a trick that can achieve what you want, which takes considerably less effort than manually renaming all your ~330 PNG files.

Run the Ghostscript command like this:

```
gs \
 -o somename--%03d.png \
 -sDEVICE=png \
 -c "showpage showpage showpage" \
 -f photobook.pdf
```

Noted the 3 `showpage` parameters? Effectively, this will insert 3 empty pages into the codestream consumed by Ghostscript. Only after these, it will process your *photobook.pdf* -- and the file numbering will start with "4". You can now throw away your first 3 .png files, or overwrite them with your additional pictures...  :-)

To make it start with "31", you have to insert 30 times the showpage.

Or, to make it easier, you can also create a 30-page PDF helper file consisting of empty pages like this:

```
gs \
 -o 30-empty.pdf \
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
 -c "1 1 30 { showpage } for"
```

and then run

```
gs \
 -o somename--%03d.png \
 -sDEVICE=png \
  30-empty.pdf \
  photobook.pdf
```